# How Google Maps API Keys work

Tags: android, api, google-maps, key

In my app i am using 3 services from google:
Google Maps API(The Map)
Google Directions (To get directions and route from point to another)
Google Places (Where i type text and suggested places start to appear on each text change)
My question here is, these 3 services use the same key?
Do i need to create a key for each service ?

Comment: You can use 1 key for all map services.

Comment: okay than i just enable the API for each service

Comment: Yes just enable API for each service.

Comment: okay thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

API-keys, unlike the name points out, are not API specific. Instead, they are side-specific (client side or server side).

If all your application is server sided then you can use one server side API key for all your requests. If instead you are simply making an HTML5 web app, without a server, then you can use a browser API key for all your requests.

Please note however, that some APIs also support API-keys. For more information about this you can read the following documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#using-google-maps-apis

Furthermore, I would like to make a small correction. There is no such thing as a Google Maps API. We do have however a JavaScritp API, which is what I believe you are using :p

Have fun and welcome !